# Angular Background Image alterations

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making a weather application using JS/HTML/CSS/Angular

I am trying to develop it so that while the weather is set to something then it will alter the background image to match.

Edit:

Here are the two codes I'm using from HTML and JS

In my html file:

```
<body ng-app="Weather" ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{newBg}})'}">
```

In my JS:

```
  if($scope.Data.des == 'Clear'){
    $scope.newBg = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfvI9.jpg';
  }

  if($scope.Data.des == 'Cloudy'){
    $scope.newBg = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfvI9.jpg';
  }
```

Image is random just to test. Doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Why use a function and in which context ? Because as I see it, it will be esaier with a ng-class in the view.

Comment: I'm trying to use ng-style. I was told that ng-style is the best way to alter background-imaging

Comment: It will be easier to create  3 class with differents background in your css. After that you just have to make a ng-class="{'class1':Data.des==''clear", 'class2':Data.des==''Cloudy" }. It will be more simple and you don't mixe css with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do 
`<body ng-app="Weather" ng-style="{{getStyle()}}">`

and in the controller, do

```
    $scope.getStyle = function(){
        var url;
        if($scope.Data.des == 'Clear'){
            url = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfvI9.jpg';
        }else if($scope.Data.des == 'Cloudy'){
            url = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfvI9.jpg';
        }
        return {"background-image":"url("+url+")"}


     }
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/kaymo/pen/NAJOQX

Here is a link to the project itself, if you could help me it would be great. I think there is something wrong with whatever I'm doing. This should be a lot easier than it's become

Comment: Thank you so much Kaushal Niraula. :)

Comment: seems you missed to include the $scope.getStyle function inside the controller. If youre satisfied, can you mark this as the answer

Comment: Works now, but only because the "else" statement.
For some reason $scope.Data.des does not read as "Clear" even though {{Data.des}} does. Strange, but this is something else to work out I guess. lol

Comment: I upvoted it, but my reputation isn't at 15. Is there somewhere that I go to confirm answer? It's not immediately on this page..

Comment: i believe theres a checkmark below the upvote/downvote button?